# Flutter Statefull widget not updating automatically from provider package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to make a cart page using the provider package and my problem is there is a remove button on the cart page and when i remove an item from the cart it does not remove it automatically but when i leave the cart widget and come back it is updated any ideas on how to fix this.

this is my cart widget

```
class CartProducts extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartProductsState createState() => _CartProductsState();
}

class _CartProductsState extends State<CartProducts> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Cart>(
      builder: (context, cart, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: cart.basketItems.length == 0
          ? Text("Cart is empty")
          : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: cart.basketItems.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(cart.basketItems[index].name),
                  trailing: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.remove), onPressed: () {
                    cart.remove(cart.basketItems[index]);
                  }),
                ),
              );
              }
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

this is my `Cart` class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'item.dart';

class Cart extends ChangeNotifier{
  List<Item> items = [];
  double totalPrice = 0.0;

  void add(Item item) {
    items.add(item);
    totalPrice += item.price;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void remove(Item item) {
    items.remove(item);
    totalPrice -= item.price;
  }

  int get count {
    return items.length;
  }

  double get totalprice {
    return totalPrice;
  }

  List<Item> get basketItems {
    return items;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to share the `ChangeNotifier` code too which is the `Cart` class.

Comment: Could you add the code from `Cart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `notifyListeners()` in the `remove` method.

```
void remove(Item item) {
    items.remove(item);
    totalPrice -= item.price;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: another question i wanted to have a quantity of every single item so every time i add a new product i want it to count how many times its added so i can get how many items from a single product is added

Comment: @Tripping that sounds like something totally unrelated to the current question. And so it should be posted as a separate question in itself.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63229974/counter-for-ever-item) can you check my post please @Jigar